# How can I construct function for client selection?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I am trying to customize to average the weights of the clients by seleceting some of the clients based on each client's sorted loss sum in this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py#L113).

```
def run_one_round(server_state, federated_dataset):
    
    server_message = tff.federated_map(server_message_fn, server_state)
    server_message_at_client = tff.federated_broadcast(server_message)

    client_outputs = tff.federated_map(
        client_update_fn, (federated_dataset, server_message_at_client))

    weight_denom = client_outputs.client_weight

    collected_output = tff.federated_collect(client_outputs)  # append     

    round_model_delta = tff.federated_map(selecting_fn,(collected_output,weight_denom))   #apppend
  
    server_state = tff.federated_map(server_update_fn,(server_state, round_model_delta))

    round_loss_metric = tff.federated_mean(client_outputs.model_output, weight=weight_denom)

    return server_state, round_loss_metric #append

@tff.tf_computation()  # append
def selecting_fn(collected_output,weight_denom):
            ...
            ...
    return round_model_delta
```

I'm trying to use `tf.math.top_k` for sorting and `tf.compat.v1.metrics.mean` for averaging.
But It doesn't work(TypError, ValueError...).
How can I construct `selecting_fn` and How to convert tensor to Federatedtype???

Comment: More detailed error you see would be helpful. For `selecting_fn`, It seems you are providing server-placed `collected_output` and clients-placed `weight_denom`, which will likely cause you a first issue.

Comment: Perhaps the first step I would recommend is to implement the `selecting_fn` you would like without the decorator, and make sure it works as expected with standard TF concepts. When that is done, proceed with TFF integration the way you outline.